# Is there any way to install a specific version of the AWS CLI utility in Unix?

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there a way to install a specific version of AWS CLI in Unix? Even with the AWS Documentation, I didn't find something configurable for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Broadly speaking, this is how you install the AWS CLI in a Unix/Linux environment:

```
pip install awscli
```

Since it uses Python's pip, [standard version syntax applies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip). To install a specific version, [I looked through the release notes](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI) to pick one out, then used the syntax seen in the linked stackoverflow question:

```
pip install awscli==1.5.0
```

Note that in a non-one-off case, I'd suggest [giving an installable range rather than a specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811418/659298), if possible:

```
pip install "awscli>=1.5.0,<=1.6.0"
```

In this case I've pretended you need something that exists in the 1.5 range but was removed in 1.6. Also note the quotes are required, otherwise you will be redirecting output to a file named "=1.5.0".

Comment: Even after mentioning version 1.11.84 ,it still says awscli version is 1.2.9

Comment: Jaswinder, I strongly suspect your problem to have been caused by the presence of multiple `pip`s on your system. Using `virtualenv`, you can avoid such problems: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: I don't think this holds for CLI v2, see the answer by Mitchell.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone not wanting to use pip the AWS CLI V2 URLs are formatted like so:

```
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2-2.X.Y.msi
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2-2.X.Y.pkg
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.X.Y.zip
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.X.Y.zip.sig
```

For example v2.0.0 on linux the links would be:

```
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.0.0.zip
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.0.0.zip.sig
```

For AWS CLI V1 the URLs for the bundled installer are formatted:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle-1.X.Y.zip
```