# Is it possible to install with pip a version range of a package from a private github repository?

Tags: python, git, pip

I am using a private github repository in order to install packages:

```
pip install --upgrade git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git#egg=mypackage
```

In the requirements.txt it looks as the following:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git#egg=mypackage
```

Afterwards, I added git tags for the versioning such as:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git@0.1.9#egg=mypackage
```

How can I define a version range such as from 0.1.9 to 1.0.0 like this example:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/mypackage.git@0.1.9<1.0.0#egg=mypackage
```

Or is it possible to use git master branch and define the version range with pip as described here:   [How to pip install a package with min and max version range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795617/how-to-pip-install-a-package-with-min-and-max-version-range)

Comment: Git tags are not version specifiers made in package metadata and can be anything, so there's no comparison mechanism provided for them.

Comment: @hoefling do you know if it is possible to use git master branch and define the version range with pip as described here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795617/how-to-pip-install-a-package-with-min-and-max-version-range

Comment: If you install from git branch, this means you install from the exact commit this branch is currently pointing to. There is no room for any version range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no room for any version range with pip+git, I will use a workaround and write a python script that will do it. This is not the most elegant way but it will work and maybe somebody finds a better approach.

Here is my workround for those facing the same issue:

1. Writing a pthon script that runs through my requirements.txt
2. Extract own git-repos with the `<git-repo>` and `<version range>`
3. The python script will call a subprocess to get a list of tags of the repo:

   `git ls-remote -t <git-repo>`
4. Extract the tags in the python script that are in the defined range as a list and take the maximum
5. Install the extracted Version which is the highest in a given range

Comment: can you share the code for this?