# Is there a way to exclude a specific version when installing a package from pypi using pip?

Tags: python, pip

In my local pypi server let's say I have 3 versions of the package `example` like below:

```
example==20200903
example==20200904 
example==202009089 # I need to exclude this
example==20200909
```

As you can see I have used date to manage our versioning, but in the middle of the versioning we have a package that has a version like `202009089` so it always match as it has a bigger number and the versioning gets broken. Is there a way to exclude that specific version when installing via `pip install` and install the latest version except `202009089`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to number future versions using a [new epoch (PEP440)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-epochs)

For example

```
version='1!20200910
```

another option is to delete the offending package from your internal pypi

another option is to select `example!=202009089` (the bad version) or pin using `example==...` (some good version)

Comment: `pip install example!=202009089` will install the latest version and also ignores the bad version. I will go this way as I do not have access to pypi server.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
pip install "example<202000000"
```

It will pick the last version before the erroneous one: `202009089`.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811418/4709400