# Pip requirements get the latest version with fixed major

Tags: python, pip

I need to find a rule to put in requirements.txt for a package `x` in order to match *any* version starting with major 3, even if they are alpha, beta, rc, whatever is the latest.

So for example that rule should match:

```
3.0.0a3
3.0.0b5
3.0.0rc2
3.0.0
3.0.1
3.1.0b0
3.1.0
...
```

whatever is the latest.

At the moment, the true latest version of `x` is 3.0.0b8.

I tried with: `x==3.*` but it doesn't work:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement x==3.* (from versions: 3.0.0b5, 3.0.0b6, 3.0.0b7, 3.0.0b8)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for x==3.*
```

I tried to read PEP440 but I couldn't figure that out. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pip install a package with min and max version range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795617/how-to-pip-install-a-package-with-min-and-max-version-range)

Comment: No luck, tried with `x>=3,<4` but still it doesn't find the current `3.0.0b8`

Comment: What is the name of the package?

Comment: I didn't mention because unfortunately it is a private package hosted on a private repo so it cannot be publicly accessed

Comment: However I believe that is something related to the pre release versions, because it seems that `>=3` won't match `3.0.0b8` because `3.0.0b8 < 3.0.0`

Comment: You are right, see [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#pre-release-versions) for a fix

Comment: As indicated the `--pre` flag works so it considers also the prerelease version, thank you!