# pip install module but with fix version in dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently had to bump a google cloud library due to a conflict that was generating a [bug](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/78). Long story short, I had

```
google-cloud-pubsub==1.4.2
```

which I had to bump to `1.4.3`. This in turn reverted `google-api-core` module to `1.16.0`, which generated a conflict with another module `google-cloud-secret-manager` which required a higher version of `google-api-core`.

Now, I have removed `google-cloud-secret-manager`. But, If I try to install the module again to the last version however, it will bump me `google-api-core` to a version not compatible with `google-cloud-pubsub`. What I want to do instead is to pip install `google-cloud-secret-manager` to the highest possible version that is compatible with `google-api-core==1.16.0` without manually trying to install all the versions until i find the right match. Is it something possible?
Is there a `pip install fix dependency version` command that could allow me to easily install `google-cloud-secret-manager` that will not change the version of the dependency module `google-api-core` to a different version? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pip install a package with min and max version range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795617/how-to-pip-install-a-package-with-min-and-max-version-range)

Comment: no sorry, that's not the question. `a_guest` answered though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [constraints file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-constraint). Just put all your constraints into that file:

```
google-api-core==1.16.0
```

Then you can install via:

```
python -m pip install -c constraints.txt google-cloud-secret-manager
```

This will try every version of `google-cloud-secret-manager`, starting from the most recent version, until it finds a version that is compatible with the given constraints.

Comment: yes it did! thank you!