# Improving docker build time for pip based python application

Tags: python, docker, pip

We have a python project, and the current docker build takes 350s. Here is the current Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python2.7

WORKDIR /var/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/var/app/src/main.py"]
```

This took 350s on every `docker build`
There was obvious room for improvement here so, I changed it to this

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python2.7

WORKDIR /var/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/var/app/src/main.py"]
```

This brings subsequent build down to 1s

I also came across the following after a bit of searching,

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python2.7

WORKDIR /var/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN  --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/var/app/src/main.py"]
```

This takes a bit longer around 80s but better than the 1st one

- What I don't understand is what are the caveats with #2 (to be safe).
- When should I use #3

I have no experience with pip/docker fyi

With #2, as a side effect of docker caching layers, if any of my dependencies dependency version changes, because of using range [operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795617/how-to-pip-install-a-package-with-min-and-max-version-range), then I still won't rebuild anything. Is that what #3 is trying to solve? i.e. it will reuse cache as much as it can but also makes sure to update anything necessary

If not, I have no idea what's going on with #3. Is the `/root/.cache/pip` a pip specific directory or it can be anything?

Comment: You use a python 3.9 base image to install Python 2.7... Logic?

Comment: that's really specific to what our app does. afaik it's historical and required without which we can't accomplish what we are trying to do.  i'm sure there are better ways to do that but we can get to that later @KevinC

EDIT: seems to be an issue with the container running on mesos hence the need for installing 2.7 along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the first two is a Docker thing.  Docker maintains a [build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache): if the previous step was cached, and either this `RUN` instruction is one that was run before or this `COPY` instruction copies identical files, then Docker skips building that layer and uses the output from the previous time you built it.

So in the first form, whenever any file changes, the `COPY` line invalidates the build cache, and you have to repeat the `RUN pip install` line.  But in the second form, you only `COPY requirements.txt .` first.  If that file hasn't changed, then you're still working off the build cache, and you can also skip the `RUN pip install` line.  This is standard Docker practice; you're not missing out on anything and there aren't really any caveats.

---

The difference between the last two is a pip thing.  Pip also [maintains a cache](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/) of things it's downloaded.  Without Docker, if you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` a second time, pip will find its local cache and avoid re-downloading files.

In Docker, though, every image build starts from the same empty image.  The `RUN --mount` option mounts a persistent directory to be the pip cache.  This on the one hand gets you a place to store the files that can be reused, and on the other avoids storing the redundant wheel files in the final image.  The mount target directory needs to be the same location as pip is expecting its cache to be.

What you should find is, if you haven't changed `requirements.txt`, then the build again skips over the `RUN pip install` step, the same as in your second Dockerfile.  If you have, then it will at least skip downloading many of the packages.  Depending on your network speed, this can lead to subsequent rebuilds running faster.

---

> ... if any of my dependencies dependency version changes ...

Most package managers have two different copies of a version list, the user-managed *dependency file* and a separate *lock file* that lists exact versions that are to be installed.

In Python the situation is a little confusing because there are several different package managers.  If I wasn't using an alternate tool like Pipfile or Poetry, then the setup I'd suggest is using the standard [Setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/) library.  [List your application's dependencies](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#declaring-required-dependency) in a `setup.cfg` file

```
[options]
install_requires =
  some-package >=1.0,<2.0
```

On your host system, use this to do the installation into a virtual environment, then run `pip freeze` to generate the `requirements.txt` file.

```sh
python3 -m venv ./venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Now the `requirements.txt` file contains the exact version of every library you directly and indirectly depend on.  Do not hand-edit this file; do not regenerate it in your Dockerfile; do check it into source control.  With the pair of dependency files, `requirements.txt` is now functionally the lock file.

Also see the pip documentation on [Repeatable Installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/repeatable-installs/).  Both Pipfile and Poetry maintain their own lock files, if you choose to use one of those package managers instead.

Comment: What do you mean by this? "The mount target directory needs to be the same location as pip is expecting its cache to be." - and how does one ensure this? Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: [`RUN --mount`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache) (or any other kind of mount) needs to mount the cache directory on some specific location.  It looks like pip [stores its cache](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/#where-is-the-cache-stored) in `$HOME/.cache/pip`, but `$HOME` is often undefined in Docker, so that may be just `/.cache/pip` in the container filesystem root directory.