# NeuralProphet on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet

m = NeuralProphet()
metrics = m.fit(df)
```

When I try to fit neuralprophet I get type error

This also happens in one of their tutorial nootebooks

Anyone knows how to fix it??

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-80f152464e03> in <module>
      8     ar_reg=0.1,
      9 )
---> 10 metrics = m.fit(df)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/neuralprophet/df_utils.py in get_normalization_params(array, norm_type)
    340     if norm_type == "soft":
    341         lowest = np.min(non_nan_array)
--> 342         q95 = np.quantile(non_nan_array, 0.95, method="higher")
    343         width = q95 - lowest
    344         if math.isclose(width, 0):

<__array_function__ internals> in quantile(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: _quantile_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

Comment: looks like you've got an old version of numpy. Upgrade to something >v1.22 and see if the error persists (I learned this by reading the `numpy.quantile` docstring)

Comment: I upgraded numpy and it changes nothing

Comment: what version of numpy are you running?

Comment: I'm using 1.21.6

Comment: My first comment noted that you needed at least v1.22

Comment: Do you know how to install it on colab bacause latest aveliable distribiution is 1.21.6??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795617/how-to-pip-install-a-package-with-min-and-max-version-range

Answer (score 0):

I have a lots of problems trying use NeuralProphet in colab, until I tried a local install through Anaconda. Then all my incompatibily problems were resolved. I recommend you use in local.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).